# Python, регулярка, регулярное выражение, паттерн

Tags: python, re

Помогите, пожалуйста... Необходимо написать регулярное выражение для поиска последовательностей из 16 цифр, где первые цифры равны "1111" или "2222"..... не могу подобрать паттерн.

```
2222150561706129, 2022/12, 689, unknown
2222158617360163, 2022/11, 575, unknown
2222157396812048, 2023/02, 134, unknown
2222156308477163, 2023/02, 894, unknown
2222156179944465, 2023/10, 444, unknown
2222159436913752, 2023/03, 767, unknown
2222159069772392, 2023/12, 450, unknown
5404374775897739, 2022/07, 270, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404372023583903, 2022/10, 658, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404372007623386, 2022/04, 208, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404370183424496, 2023/06, 916, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404373907869285, 2022/03, 161, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404372265914105, 2022/05, 244, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404376974905908, 2023/11, 148, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404377654669145, 2023/11, 316, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404377630544941, 2023/06, 186, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
5404375880479032, 2023/02, 442, MasterCard - Lloyds Tsb Bank Plc., UK
2222150180636897001, 2022/11, 343, unknown
2222158452830726112, 2023/05, 201, unknown
222215519534593999999, 2022/11, 609, unknown
1111156743043261, 2022/12, 805, unknown
1111150617237653, 2022/11, 515, unknown
1111155357175286, 2023/04, 311, unknown
1111150615518179, 2022/07, 513, unknown
1111151535854942, 2022/09, 952, unknown
1111156750422077, 2023/01, 635, unknown
5177438360790180, 2023/05, 853, MasterCard - Credit Suisse, Switzerland
5522008749880747, 2022/03, 135, MasterCard - HSBC Bank Malta P.L.C., Malta
5218417540145854, 2023/08, 976, MasterCard - Ubs Ag, Switzerland
5177439042819454, 2023/12, 722, MasterCard - Credit Suisse, Switzerland
4664651289110800, 2022/12, 311, Visa
5288776273847142, 2023/11, 837, MasterCard - Banco Nacional De Mexico, S.A.
5137474107054324, 2022/08, 998, MasterCard - Europay France Sas, France
5288779610520984, 2023/10, 914, MasterCard - Banco Nacional De Mexico, S.A.
5520717826332883, 2023/09, 708, MasterCard - Banco Bilbao Vizcaya Argentaria S.A., Spain
5369907162247324, 2022/11, 782, MasterCard - Chase Manhattan Bank USA, USA
```

Comment: Где Ваши попытки?

Comment: Нифига себе кредиток засветил - скорее всего за тобой уже выехали)))

Comment: @SergBocharov ;D Небось просто случайные сгенерированные ;)

Comment: Может быть, но тут и сроки и CVV, плюс пробиваются по банкам, алгоритм известен, сайты тоже. Хотя откуда тогда левые 1111 или 2222 в начале? )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
(1|2){4}\d{4}
```

;)